# I couldn't use the pen pressure feature of Wacom tablet within Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, wacom

I am using a Wacom Intuos Art tablet in my Windows 10 PC. I am trying to use the brush tool with pen pressure control in Photoshop CC but it doesn't work. I can see an alert icon near control option in the brush tab.

I have even tried "clear brush controls" option but that didn't fix the issue.

I am facing this issue only with Photoshop. The pen pressure feature works great with Illustrator, Affinity Designer and such.

Please help me troubleshoot the problem!

[image]

My Wacom intuos driver info, this is the latest version.

[image]

My Photoshop CC version

[image]

Comment: Are you using the most recent driver from the Wacom site? The drivers on the disk that comes in the box are often outdated. This is a tech support question, and as such it's off topic here. You might be better contacting Wacom directly for support if updating the drivers doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it is up to date.

Comment: The problem is now solved! I just enabled the windows ink option, and it worked.

Comment: Actually this problem could surprise anyone who gets a new Wacom tablet. For me this is useful case because soon I'm one of those lucky. Write your own solution as an answer and accept it. Hurry because soon this is voted out and the really useful story fades to nonexistence.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks, I didn't know that I could even answer my own question. Now I have posted the solution to my problem.

Comment: Accept it, too. This means = Solved. No reason to shame. I will not remove my comments.

Comment: Please accept your own answer!

Comment: @Luciano I can only do that after 24 hours of posting. 8 more hours to go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by enabling **"Use Windows Ink"** option under Mapping tab in the Wacom properties. Make sure you are doing so with Photoshop selected under application.

Though, I couldn't understand why pen pressure works on applications like Illustrator, affinity designer even without enabling the "Use Windows Ink" option.

[image]